# angularjs 2 directives share link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible for 2 directives to use the same linking function? They have different templates but are otherwise the same. They don't require each other so I don't want to use transcluded / require. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the templates the only things that differ?

Comment: @tasseKATT yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a factory/service which implements your logic and inject it in both directives. Call it in both link functions. Done.

Answer (score 0):

you really don't want to do this as directives create their own scope once isolated.  also they have their own element, attrs values to pass on.

Comment: I just want to share code, they don't use the same scope or whatever.